# Let $T:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $T(p)=p-p'$. Find all eigen values and eigen vectors of $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $T(p)=p-p'$. Find all eigen values and eigen vectors of $T$.

Please someone help me with this problem. Thank you

Comment: Forgive me if this is a dumb question, but what is $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$? Is it the set of polynomials in one variable with real coefficients?

Comment: what have you got so far?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2):

I will assume $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of polynomials with real coefficients. Then if $p$ is an eigenvector of $T$, we have $T p = p - p' = \lambda p$. By comparing the leading coefficients, we have that $\lambda =1$, so that $p'=0$, and $p=c$ for some constant $c$. Thus there is only one eigenvalue, $\lambda=1$, with corresponding eigenspace $\langle 1 \rangle$.

Comment: What about $p=\alpha p'$?

Comment: @celtschk by comparing degrees, that is impossible unless $p=0$, in which case it is not an eigenvector.

Comment: I don't see anything stating a specific degree of $p'$.

Comment: @celtschk We are working over the reals which is characteristic 0, since $p$ is nonzero, if $p$ has degree $n$, then $p'$ has degree $n-1$, and hence $p$ cannot be a scalar multiple of $p'$.

Comment: Ah, I understand, you interpret "$p'$" as "derivative of $p$". I interpreted it as some constant value independent of $p$ that is also a polynomial. Which shows how important it is to properly specify the problem. :-)

Comment: @celtschk Indeed, that hadn't occurred to me, I see. Yes, that would certainly change things. :)

Comment: The notation $p'$ is pretty standard.